# Distributed Training DeepLabv3+ with Google Cloud ML

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-ml

I'm a bit new to Google Cloud ML and having difficulties adapting distributed training to a model. I'm trying to train [Google's DeepLabv3+](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/deeplab) on Google Cloud ML with a custom training set using the Standard_1 Scale Tier and it passes in a `TF_CONFIG` value that describes the cluster.

It works fine locally, but it of course takes forever because it's just a laptop. According to [this](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/distributed-training-details#tensorflow-config) I should be able to use the `TF_CONFIG` variable to set up a distributed training job. In the [training task](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/deeplab/train.py#L37-L54) there are some parameters that talk about distributed training but it doesn't seem to match any of the other distributed training documentation I've seen (ie Using `tf.train.ClusterSpec`).

Can somebody give me a push in the right direction for this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to Google Cloud ML, I suggest you to follow first this [official tutorial in github](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/tree/master/census) for Google Cloud ML to observe differences between running in local or using ML Engine.

Then, have a look on the `--scale-tier` command mentioned in [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/getting-started-training-prediction#cloud-train-dist), which is used to run distributed training. Bare in mind that you could income on some costs performing [distributed training operations](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/pricing#pricing_overview).